# Run on all files in a directory, treating each separately, using AWK

Tags: file, variables, search, awk

I want to run an AWK script on each file in a directory, but the AWK command must run only within that file - that is, it searches between a defined RS and returns what it is supposed to, but I need it to stop when it reaches the end of one file, and begin again at the start of the next file.

I have this running which works on each file individually:

```
awk '!/value1|value2/ && NF {print FILENAME " - " RS,$1}' RS="value" file1 > result.txt
```

But the output isn't correct, say, when applying it to each file in a directory using

```
find . -type f | awk ... file1 > result.txt
```

How would I get it to look at each file individually, but append the results into the same file? I have no idea unfortunately. I guess it's by adding each file into a variable and having AWK look at that, but I am not sure how to do it.

#### File file1:

```
interface Vlan3990
 ip address 172.17.226.23 255.255.255.254
```

#### File file2:

```
version 12.2
ip tacacs source-interface Loopback99
ip vrf test
 description xx
interface Loopback99
 description Management Loopback
interface Loopback100
 shutdown
```

#### Output

```
find . -type f | xargs awk '!/description|shutdown/ && NF {print FILENAME " - " RS,$1}' RS="interface" | more
./file1 - interface Vlan3990
./file2 - interface version
```

I am not sure where the output 'interface version' is coming from...

Comment: shell script to call awk on each file, separately? or BEGIN/BEGINFILE/END/ENDFILE implemented as needed?

Comment: yes - so it looks at one file, runs the command, stops, then opens the next file in the directory, runs the command, stops etc... not sure how to get it to do this as there are 300+ files in the directory

Comment: Can you elaborate the sentence **but the output isn't correct**? Which are the differences between what you get and what you expect?

Comment: in each file there is a last occurrence of the RS, so it looks and returns between the last occurrence in the first file and the first occurrence of the second file...

Comment: Clarify what you're trying to do with come sample input and expected output as you seem to be asking for a workaround to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: ok. thanks ed. one sec.

Comment: Is "output" above the output you want or the output you current get that you don't want? If the latter, what output do you want?

Comment: The output "interface version", by the way, is coming from you setting RS="version" and then printing RS followed by $1 so when $1 is "version" on the first line of file2 you get that output.

Comment: ok... i would expect to see an output of all lines beginning with 'interface' that do not have lines beginning with either 'shutdown' or 'description' following until the next instance of a line beginning with 'interface'. essentially, it's cisco config - and i want it to print all interfaces that aren't shut down and don't have a description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, given your 2 posted input files:

```
$ gawk '
    function prtName() {
        if (name)
            print FILENAME, name
        name=""
    }
    /^interface/                { prtName(); name=$0 }
    /^ (description|shutdown)/  { name="" }
    ENDFILE                     { prtName() }
' file1 file2
file1 interface Vlan3990
```

Is that what you're looking for? Note that it's gawk-specific (courtesy of `ENDFILE`) which I assume is fine since the sample command you posted is also gawk-specific but if that's an issue just add a test for FNR==1 and change ENDFILE to END:

```
$ awk '
    function prtName() {
        if (name)
            print filename, name
        name=""
    }
    FNR==1                      { prtName(); filename=FILENAME }
    /^interface/                { prtName(); name=$0 }
    /^ (description|shutdown)/  { name="" }
    END                         { prtName() }
' file1 file2
file1 interface Vlan3990
```

Comment: need the name of the file it prints the result from, not sure how to print it at the beginning of each line?

Comment: The script does print the file name at the beginning of each output line, take another look. I did originally post a script that didn't print the file name so maybe you saw that before I edited it.

Comment: thankyou very much ed. this is exactly what i was trying to get.

Answer (score 9):

For just the current directory:

```
for file in *
do awk ... "$file"
done > result.txt
```

If you need to recurse into subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -exec awk ... {} ; > result.txt
```

In both cases, you should probably put `result.txt` in a different directory. Otherwise, it will be matched and used as an input file. Or use a wildcard that only matches the desired files, and doesn't match `result.txt`.

Comment: There's no need for that loop, awk is perfectly capable of running on multiple files.

Comment: This concatenates all files into a single file right? How about writing each file to itself? like a sed inplace?