# Check if a particular text is present in the first column in all files under subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a directory which has many subdirectories having .bed files in each of them. The .bed files have the following format:

```
Chromosome<tab> Start<tab> Stop
```

The Chromosome column has the chromosome number and the column values can be represented either as `'chr1'` or `'1'`. I want to list those bed files which do not have `'chr'` characters in the first column of the .bed files, how can I do that?

Comment: Please include some snippets of the files and describe in more detail the desired result.

Comment: You need to take a stab at it yourself... what have you tried? I suggest pairing awk with a shell script. The bottom answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498568/awk-run-on-all-files-in-directory-treating-each-separately) should get you started.

Comment: If Glenn's answer below helped you solve your problem you should consider accepting his answer so your question doesn't keep floating around as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name \*.bed -exec grep -lv '^chr' '{}' +
```